# How to wrap divs around each letter in a user given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, keyup, digit

I'm trying to make a small web app, and would like to let users enter text - which the app will simply parse PER LETTER, making a small div for each character entered (including spaces).

The code is working alright but I can't seem to separate each letter in the output. Currently I'm only able to wrap a new div around the string as a whole.

#userString is a text box, when user types the output in #stringPush should be identical to the input, but with a div and span wrapped around each letter (.letter ui-draggalble span #sort).

I'm certain that my use of 'for' to look for each letter is where the problem lies. Any thoughts or advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
$('#userString').keyup(function() 
{
    var txt = $('input:text[id=userString]').val();
    for( var x = 0, c=''; c = txt.charAt(x); x++)
    { 
        $('#stringPush').html(txt).wrapInner("<div class='letter ui-draggable'><span id='sort'></span></div>");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S7FJ8/5/ Here is the entirety of the code.. sigh. Probably shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#userString').keyup(function() {
    var txt = $.trim(this.value).split('');
    $('#stringPush').html(function() {
        return $.map(txt, function(letter) {
            return "<div class='letter ui-draggable'><span class='sort'>"+letter+"</span></div>"
        });
    });
});
```

Please note that IDs must be unique, I have change the `id` attribute to a className.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZRZS/

Comment: YES! Thanks a bundle!! I've got another problem though with spaces being very important. Could this code be used to create the same div/span combo for spaces? Yeah I've never seen .map previously either.

Comment: @JellyAce It iterates through the array and returns a new array based on the returned values of the callback.

Comment: I don't think I got what you mean. Haha. I'll just test to see what it does. Thank you!

Comment: Somehow, these divs aren't available for jquery-ui dragging. could they be contained to their div only? they don't even seem to be available despite the others on the page working great. I've updated the jsfiddle to include both. CHEERS!

Comment: @user3594223 You are welcome, as JellyAce mentions you can remove the `$.trim` call. `var txt = (this.value).split('');`

Comment: I tried removing $.trim though and spaces appeared as divs smaller than usual.

Comment: @JellyAce there aren't any min/max widths on the css. could be why.

Comment: Yea. I completely ignored the CSS. Haha.

Comment: There, updated the css with min/max so it looks proper. If I could only find a way to make them draggable now... Thanks folks!

Comment: @user3594223 You should call the draggable after each html-resetting. Within the `keyup` callback.

Comment: YEAHYA! it fully worked. I just tossed another 
    $( ".letter" ).draggable( {
       containment: 'window',
       cursor: 'pointer',
       helper: 'clone'
    });   call just after the stringPush).html call AND IT WORKED! Thanks so so so much.

Comment: Feel like learning how to put away antique letterpress pieces? HAHA. http://jobcasetest.info/PrintShop.php  Have a great night!! Boatloads of thanks!